# Sources for macro economic forecast data

Tags: data-request

I need data for these long run(atleast 10year forward) macroeconomic parameters from 2000, meaning I need forecasted data as in 2000 for 2010 so I can backtest my model with actual realised data:

Long run aggregate gdp growth

Long run population forecast by age groups

Long run inflation forecast

Current account deficit forecasts

Kindly provide me all available sources to such data.

Answer (score 1):

GDP: If I remember correctly, Congressional budget office offers 10-12 yr forward potential gdp every quarter, from which you can derive predicted potential growth.

PopGrowth: U.S. Census has this data

Inflation: Fed Res/Philidelphia provides inflation forecast

Account deficit: All the sources for 5 or more years forecast in int. trade are either proprietary or highly unreliable. Best of luck in your search.